# Using std::istream_iterator to read up to N values

Tags: c++

If I know for certain that my input stream contains 10 values, I can read them with

```
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<T>(input), 10, output);
```

If I don't know how much values I have, I can read all of them with

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<T>(input), std::istream_iterator<T>(), output);
```

My problem is how to read *up to* 10 values. I'm trying to be robust against I/O errors here,
but it appears that `copy_n` will try to read past the end of the input (it doesn't know that it should stop), and `copy` won't stop at 10 values. Do I have to roll my own `copy_at_most`?

<sub>(Well, there's apparently some confusion about copy_n anyway: [std::istream_iterator<> with copy_n() and friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074122/stdistream-iterator-with-copy-n-and-friends?rq=1) )</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, there is currently in general no way to limit the number of processed elements using STL algorithms. My personal view is that `std::copy()` should take two ranges both delimited by begin and end. If either end can't be reached the corresponding range would be unbounded. That is, if anything I would roll my own `copy()` algorithm like this:

```
template <typename InIt, typename OutIt>
std::pair<InIt, OutIt>
copy(InIt init, InIt inend, OutIt outit, OutIt outend) {
    for (; init != inend && outit != outend; ++init, ++outit) {
        *outit = *init;
    }
    return std::make_pair(init, outit);
}
```

To deal with the current iterator system, the comparison between output iterators actually can't be done. Thus, the comparison for output iterator actually requires a bit of template programming to make sure actual output iterators are never compared and, instead, `true` is returned. For all other iterator classes the above algorithm should just work (assuming I didn't introduce any typos).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `copy_if` and a counter - that unfortunately doesn't break early.

```
int count = 0;
std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<T>(input), std::istream_iterator<T>(), output,
    [&]() { return ++count < 10; });
```

If you'd like to stick with algorithms (instead of plain `for` loop), I'd suggest you roll you own (I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055138/combining-c-standard-algorithms-by-looping-only-once/14055955#14055955) in the past.)